# Display Model Field in Razor that Matches Criteria

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

What is the best way to display a Model value where the other fields in the element match criteria?  For example, here is a model:

```
public class PricesModel
{
    public int PriceID { get; set; }
    public DateTime PriceDate { get; set; }
    public int ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

A list of that type model is included in a View's ViewModel:

```
public class PricesViewModel
{
    public List<PricesModel> Prices { get; set; }
    //Additional data
}
```

And in the View, we have a table like this:

```
@model PricesViewModel
<table class="table">
    <tr class="info">
        <th><em>Price IDs</em></th>
        <th>@String.Format("{0:d MMM yyyy}", new DateTime(2015,12,1))</th>
        <th>@String.Format("{0:d MMM yyyy}", new DateTime(2016,1,1)</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row" >12345</th>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So, the entries in the table cells would be: the PriceID where PriceDate = 1 Dec 2015 and ZipCode = 12345, and the PriceID where PriceDate = 1 Jan 2016 and ZipCode = 12345.  I've seen some questions related to this using Python, but not Razor.  I've tried things like the below, but none has worked:

```
@Model.PricesModel.PriceID.Where(i => Model.PricesModel[i].ZipCode == 12345).ToString()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not load data only matching your condition to the view model in your action method ?. Also, you need to loop through the Prices collection to get each property value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a c# question. And I recommend that you put this logic elsewhere, but here goes.

```
@Model.Prices.FirstOrDefault( p => p.ZipCode == 12345 && p.PriceDate.Date == new DateTime(2015, 12, 1 ) )?.PriceId
```

Comment: Thanks all - I will mark this correct because it technically answers the question, but I will redesign the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the logic in the controller (this is all that ModelViewController (MVC) is about).

In the controller you return PricesModel with the filtered prices.

You could filter the list the way you want in the controller.